# query executa no banco mas no projeto aponta erro

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Tenho um *query* nativa:

```
SELECT dist.nome Distrito,
    enti.nome Entidade,
    dist.id_distrito,
    dist.codigo_dne,
    dist.id_entidade,
    dist.id_municipio,
    dist.id_uf,
    dist.flag_ativo,
    muni.nome Municipio,
    unfe.nome UF
FROM glb.distritos  dist,
    glb.entidades  enti,
    glb.municipios muni,
    glb.ufs        unfe
WHERE dist.id_entidade  = enti.id_entidade
AND dist.id_municipio = muni.id_municipio
AND muni.id_uf        = unfe.id_uf
```

Tentei usar em um projeto JPA/Hibernate usando a anotação:

```
 ´nativeQuery=true´
```

E não funcionou no projeto, apareceu esse erro no log:

```
A nome da coluna nome não foi encontrado neste ResultSet.
```

Mas executando a query no banco Postgres ele traz a informação.

O erro aparece quando eu faço uma solicitação do script da tela

```
$http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/user/distritos'
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.distritos = response.data;

        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });
```

para a API
Na API tenho o método

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/distritos", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Distritos>> buscarTodosDistritos() {
        Collection<Distritos> distritosBuscados = distritosService.buscarFiltro();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(distritosBuscados, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

no método `distritosService.buscarFiltro();`

```
@Query( nativeQuery=true,  value="SELECT dist.nome Distrito, dist.id_distrito, dist.id_entidade, dist.id_municipio, dist.id_uf, dist.codigo_dne, dist.flag_ativo,  enti.nome Entidade, muni.nome Municipio, unfe.nome UF FROM glb.distritos  dist, glb.entidades  enti, glb.municipios muni, glb.ufs unfe WHERE dist.id_entidade  = enti.id_entidade AND dist.id_municipio = muni.id_municipio AND muni.id_uf = unfe.id_uf ")
    public  Collection<Distritos>  buscarFiltro();
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o setor do código que ele retorna esse erro?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar  editei a pergunta..

Comment: Não existe mesmo nenhuma coluna `nome` no `ResultSet`, já que você está usando aliases para elas: `dist.nome Distrito`, `enti.nome Entidade`, etc. Apenas para ver isto use  apenas `dist.nome`

Comment: @BrunoCésar você estava certo. Funcionou. Posta como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua query é sim válida, como você mesmo observou ao executá-la diretamente num cliente SQL.

O problema é que você está usando [*aliases*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) na consulta, exatamente nas chamadas `nome`, nomeando-as como `Distrito`, `Entidade`, `Municipio` e `UF`. Quando o *provider* JPA tenta fazer o *binding* do `ResultSet` para a entidade ele não encontra nenhuma coluna chamada `nome`, por conta do *output name*.

No teu caso, basta alterar a consulta para algo assim:

```sql
SELECT dist.nome,
    enti.nome Entidade,
    dist.id_distrito,
    dist.codigo_dne,
    dist.id_entidade,
    dist.id_municipio,
    dist.id_uf,
    dist.flag_ativo,
    muni.nome Municipio,
    unfe.nome UF
FROM glb.distritos  dist,
    glb.entidades  enti,
    glb.municipios muni,
    glb.ufs        unfe
WHERE dist.id_entidade  = enti.id_entidade
AND dist.id_municipio = muni.id_municipio
AND muni.id_uf        = unfe.id_uf
```

Isto fará com que no `ResultSet` tenha a coluna chamada `nome`, veja que apenas removemos o *alias* de uma das colunas que originalmente se chama `nome`.